# Avoiding the Yellow Triangle when using failed steps for flow control in an Agent job

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent

I have a multi-step agent job in SQL Server 2012 that uses the success or failure of job steps for flow control. In the image below, step 3 checks for the existence of a file with a Powershell script that signals a failure when the file is not found. On failure, it goes to step 7 and sends an email. On success (or failure) of step 7, the job proceeds to step 11 and does a similar search for another file.

The job at 2:34:34 found both files and ran them through an SSIS package, while the job at 2:27:39 could not read the files, and sent an email to that effect before signaling a job failure. The job run at 2:31:23 functionally succeeded. It found no files, popped off a couple of emails, and finished.But if any step of a job signals a failure, the entire job is marked with the yellow caution triangle.

[image: Log File Viewer]

Is there any way of using flow control in an Agent job that will result in a check mark instead of a caution?

Comment: As far as I know, this is just standard Microsoft behavior for log viewers. You would have to set logic at the step level to not fail the step for certain conditions. That or set this logic on the SSIS package itself. This has more to do with your design than anything else.

Comment: I was afraid that might be the case. I'll just have to come up with a different design if I really want to avoid the symbol. Hardly a big problem, after all. The customer never sees these.